# Cannot convert object to primitive value in converting object into URL encoded string

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to convert an object to a URL encoded string using this functions:

```
console.log(jQuery.param($scope.employee));

console.log($.param($scope.employee));
```

But they give me an error of:

> TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
>       at encodeURIComponent ()
>       at e (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
>       at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
>       at Function.r.param (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
>       at m.$scope.save (employees.js:49)
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:241), :4:388)
>       at e (angular.min.js:286)
>       at m.$eval (angular.min.js:149)
>       at m.$apply (angular.min.js:150)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (angular.min.js:286)

The value of `$scope.employee`

```
Data: Object
contact_number:"112"
created_at:"2017-08-08 05:27:03"
email:"asd@111.com"
id:9
name:"re"
position:"a"
updated_at:"2017-08-08 05:27:03"
```

This is developed using Laravel and AngularJS hosted on HomeStead.
Jquery is installed.

Update for verification purposes only:

Modal HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{form_title}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form name="frmEmployees" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">
<div class="form-group error">
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Fullname" value="{{employee.data.name}}" 
    ng-model="employee.data.name" ng-required="true">
    <span class="help-inline" 
    ng-show="frmEmployees.name.$invalid && frmEmployees.name.$touched">Name field is required</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="{{employee.data.email}}" 
    ng-model="employee.data.email" ng-required="true">
    <span class="help-inline" 
    ng-show="frmEmployees.email.$invalid && frmEmployees.email.$touched">Valid Email field is required</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact Number</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Contact Number" value="{{employee.data.contact_number}}" 
    ng-model="employee.data.contact_number" ng-required="true">
<span class="help-inline" 
    ng-show="frmEmployees.contact_number.$invalid && frmEmployees.contact_number.$touched">Contact number field is required</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Position</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" name="position" placeholder="Position" value="{{employee.data.position}}" 
    ng-model="employee.data.position" ng-required="true">
<span class="help-inline" 
    ng-show="frmEmployees.position.$invalid && frmEmployees.position.$touched">Position field is required</span>
</div>
</div>

</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" ng-click="save(modalstate, employee.data.id)" ng-disabled="frmEmployees.$invalid">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note: In the tutorial I was following the value for the `ng-model` was this: `employee.position` but I changed it to `employee.data.position` for the reason that when I will update the record the values are not populated in the field but after adding `data` the values are now populated.

I am just starting to learn about Laravel and AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Angular you can use **$httpParamSerializerJQLike**, sample code:

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

  $http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

});
```

[Angular documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Comment: There is some problem with the converted value `data%5Bid%5D=13&data%5Bname%5D=aa%20aa&data%5Bemail%5D=aa%40sdd.com&data%5Bcontact_number%5D=123&data%5Bposition%5D=a&data%5Bcreated_at%5D=2017-08` there are data values in between.

Comment: Is there a way to make it look like this: `data%5Bcontact_number%5D=123&data%5Bemail%5D=adc@ss.com&data%5Bname%5D=cc+aa&data%5Bposition%5D=as`

Comment: is it not parsing on server side?

Comment: It works now I just let it as is. Will you be able to enlighten me as to why `$.param` is not working? I'm following a tutorial. Thank you

Comment: i would be able to clarify if  you provide me more code, because usually $.param works

Comment: I provided the HTML modal code where I did change the code posted in the tutorial as it was not working or so I believe "I may be wrong". The `$.param` works fine when I'm creating new records but it fails when I'm updating.

Comment: it must be scope problem then, since i have used angular sterilizer so its working, in your case scope must not be updating somehow.

Comment: Thank you. I will use $httpParamSerializerJQLike from now on instead of $.param

Answer (score 1):

this can be done without jQuery

```
var serialize = function(obj, prefix) {
  var str = [], p;
  for(p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
      str.push((v !== null && typeof v === "object") ?
        serialize(v, k) :
        encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
  }
  return str.join("&");
}
```

usage `console.log(serialize($scope.employee))`

Comment: how do i call serialize?

Comment: oops. my mistake.

Comment: There is some problem with the converted value `data%5Bid%5D=13&data%5Bname%5D=aa%20aa&data%5Bemail%5D=aa%40sdd.com&data%5Bcontact_number%5D=123&data%5Bposition%5D=a&data%5Bcreated_at%5D=2017-08` there are data values in between

Comment: your data contain nested object?